# JQuery Ajax call not sending a response back

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Although the ajax call is sending the correct values and they are being written to the database I'm not getting a response back.

I have cut the code down to the minimum to try and locate the error but I still can't get a response...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#change_username').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
           dataType: "json",
           type: "POST",
           url: "ajax/change_password_ajax.php",
           data: $('#change_password_form').serialize(),
           success:function(response){
               smeg = (response.message),
               alert(smeg)
               }    

         });
     });
});
```

change_password_ajax.php

```
$new_password = $_POST['new_password1'];

$new_password = md5($new_password);
    $sql = "UPDATE user SET password = '$new_password' WHERE userID = '$id'";
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
    if($result){
        $message = 'yes';   
    }

    $output_array = array(
          'message' => $message,
          'bob' => 'yellow'
        );

echo json_encode($output_array);
```

If I use Firebug the post to change_password_ajax.php is highlighted in red and there are no response or html tabs but it doesn't give an indication why.

Comment: There should be an error message assigned with that response in the console. If you click that you should get more info, such as the response code and possibly the exact error.

Comment: nope, it's red with a cross and 0ms.  If I click on it I can see the headers, the values posted and the sent cookies

Comment: can you see a syntax error?  If you can  would be very grateful if you can tell me where

Comment: In the success callback, put `console.dir(response);` as the very first line, then check the console to see what's actually being returned.

Comment: I get 'uncaught exception: out of memory

Line 0'

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Edited: Didn't see the first sentence in his question.

In your AJAX call, you have included a "success" callback, but you have not included an "error" callback. If you add one, you will have access to the error object, which is needed for error handling, but can also give you more information on the failure.

However, in your case, you're saying the data is being saved to the database - so the request must be working. The error either lies after the database request is made (the json_encode?) or, the front end in processing the response)

Check your apache log for PHP errors to see if you can pinpoint what's happening.

Edited 2:

Looking at your comments, this other stack overflow question looks like it might glean some answers:

[uncaught exception: out of memory in Ajax Process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29291952/uncaught-exception-out-of-memory-in-ajax-process)

If your button is a submit button, you might want to preventDefault() on the button.

Comment: I added the error code and get 'uncaught exception: out of memory

Line 0'.  I've checked the form is serialising ok but it isn't red in the network tab

Comment: back end in the console

Comment: Sorry, can you clarify. Do you mean the javascript console? Is this error in the response from your script, or is that the error javascript is giving? Or is this error in your apache log?

Comment: it is the error the javascript script is giving in the console, there are no apache errors for the php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29291952/uncaught-exception-out-of-memory-in-ajax-process

I wonder if this answer helps?

Comment: My error was that I was converting a php posting form to ajax and the button was still a submit button.  Changing it solved the issue, thank you for your help.