# jQuery AJAX response giving error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

jQuery code

```
$.ajax({
    url: "far-area_m.php",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: values ,
    success: function (response) {
        alert("sdfds");
        // you will get response from your php page (what you echo or print)                        
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus);
        console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
    }               
});
```

far-area_m.php

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$dbname='lateral';

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$len = $_REQUEST["len"];
$bre = $_REQUEST["bre"];
$wid = $_REQUEST["wid"];

$sql = mysqli_query(
    $conn,
    "INSERT INTO `far_input` (`length`, `breadth`, `width`)
    VALUES
    ('".$len."', '".$bre."', '".$wid."')
    ");
$data = array(
    'len'     => $len,
    'bre'  => $bre,
    'wid'   => $wid
);

echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

always Ajax response is printing error.But if I comment the insert statement in *far-area_m.php* I am getting response. Please tell me what is wrong with the code.
on sucess of jquery I am not getting any response its throwing error.

Comment: One `*` in your code before `data array`!!

Comment: after changing also its same

Comment: if you run the insert statement by providing values, does it work ???

Comment: Check browser   console for error!!!

Comment: whats exactly the error from the ajax response?

Comment: error is uncaught exception: out of memory

Comment: check this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29291952/uncaught-exception-out-of-memory-in-ajax-process

Answer (score 0):

You posted an incomplete ajax code. Hope you will find what you are doing wrong there, may be error is happening because of not using`return false;`at the end of code.It stops form submission manually.

your code should be like this:

```
$('#form').submit(function(){

var values = $('#form').serialize();

$.ajax({
url: "far-area_m.php",
type: "POST",
dataType: 'json',
data: values ,
success: function (response) {
    alert("sdfds");
   // you will get response from your php page (what you echo or print)                 
},
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert(textStatus);
   console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
}


});
return false;
});
```